# httpd and mod_security woth OWASP's dos rules

Tags: security, apache-httpd

I'm trying to setup the mod_security on my httpd web server. I have followed the basic steps

```
yum install mod_security
```

1. I put the `modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf` in the `/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d`
2. I put the owasp dos rule in the `/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated-rules`
3. I have checked that `/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf` includes these 2 `.conf`
4. I have checked that `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` includes the `/etc/httpd/conf.d` folder.

When I start http and check in the `/var/log/httpd` I can see that `modsecurity_auditlog` is created and that it logs all the error (5x and 4x)

```
--b7148938-H--
Apache-Handler: proxy-server
Stopwatch: 1419172908440055 2294 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1419172908440055 2294; combined=242, p1=98, p2=8, p3=0, p4=1, p5=84, sr=32, sw=51, l=0, gc=0
Response-Body-Transformed: Dechunked
Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.8.0 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); **OWASP_CRS/2.2.9.**
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (xxx)
Engine-Mode: "ENABLED"
```

I have then started Low Orbit Ion Cannon and spammed my index page for 5 minutes. And.... nothing. I have no mention whatsoever that the server was under DOS attack (I checked in the modsecurity audit log and http error log.)

To test a little I have modified the variable in the `.conf` from owasp (I have a very low threshold and a smaller burst time slice)

```
#SecAction \
  "id:'900015', \
  phase:1, \
  t:none, \
  setvar:'**tx.dos_burst_time_slice=10'**, \
  setvar:'**tx.dos_counter_threshold=5**', \
  setvar:'tx.dos_block_timeout=600', \
  nolog, \
  pass"
```

But still nothing. My IP was still not blocked.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the # from the #SecAction in the snippet you quoted for rule 900015. There's a line just above this telling you to do this if using DoS rules.

Comment: I had realize it after a while, but yes that was the problem  :p